# $_SESSION in PHP

Tags: php, session, key

I'm trying to achieve something like $_SESSION[$key] without the need of foreach loop, how can I achieve this? Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain where is the foreach loop?

Comment: Show us your current code, then tell us why you want to change it.

Comment: I'm trying to assign $_POST['id'] to $_SESSION['id']. id within both is same but dynamic. Therefore, I need $_SESSION's index to be dynamic so I can relate to particular values.

Comment: Still not quite clear what you're asking for. What about `$_SESSION[$key] = $_POST[$key]`? Or do you want to do that for *all* keys in `$_POST`?

Comment: @froufrou : If you only want to assign all data of POST to SESSION then $_SESSION = $_POST;

Comment: @Poonam, unless there is already something in session that he doesn't want to clobber unnecessarily

Comment: @tobyodavies: IF something in session then just store it first in other variable then again add in session after post get added. Or use array_push function to push values in session

Comment: @Poonam, he wanted to avoid a `foreach` loop either of those suggestions require either a loop or a known, finite number of keys. its much easier to just use array_merge, in fact the first suggestion leaves him in exactly the same situation he started in - data in two arrays that he wants in 1 - it doesn't take him any closer to his goal whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) will do more or less what you want assuming id is never numeric and you want to put *everything* in `$_POST` into `$_SESSION`, which may not be a good idea

```
$_SESSION=array_merge($_SESSION,$_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is sorted, I had to include single quotes in $_SESSION's index in order to make it treat like a non-numeric index.

Thanks for the help guys!